# Read file line by line using fstream into a 2d vector in C++

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

The contents of the input.txt file are:

```
45 15 87 12
12 48 878 7
11 25 85 44
```

**Note: There is no space between the last number on each line and the line break.**
How do I read the file and store it's contents as a 2d vector which represents a matrix. The vector should look like this:

```
    vector<vector<int>> vect
    {
        {45 15 87 12},
        {12 48 878 7},
        {11 25 85 44}
    };
```

Describing a 3x4 matrix

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Tested and works

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    istringstream input(R"(45 15 87 12
12 48 878 7
11 25 85 44)");

    vector<vector<int>> vect;
    // go through each line of file
    string line;
    while (getline(input, line)) {
        istringstream line_ss(line);
        vector<int> row;
        // go through each number on line
        for (int element; line_ss >> element;) {
            // insert number into row
            row.push_back(element);
        }
        // insert row into vect
        vect.push_back(row);
    }
    cout << "done" << endl;
}
```

Should hopefully be pretty self explanitory, I used istringstream instead of ifstream but both should work. Let me know if you want an explanation of any part.

Edit: And someone else has linked this to a post that also has a similar solution, so use that for additional information as well as it seems to explain it more.